# AWS Athena: how to handle the data from GetQueryResultsCommand command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

After retrieving an Athena query result (stored in a CSV file in a  S3 bucket) by using the Athena client and the command ***GetQueryResultsCommand***,
the data retrieved are structured in the following way:

```
{
   "NextToken": "string",
   "ResultSet": { 
      "ResultSetMetadata": { 
         "ColumnInfo": [ 
            { 
               "CaseSensitive": boolean,
               "CatalogName": "string",
               "Label": "string",
               "Name": "string",
               "Nullable": "string",
               "Precision": number,
               "Scale": number,
               "SchemaName": "string",
               "TableName": "string",
               "Type": "string"
            }
         ]
      },
      "Rows": [ 
         { 
            Data: [
              { VarCharValue: 'columnName1' },
              { VarCharValue: 'columnName2' },
              { VarCharValue: 'columnName3' },
              { VarCharValue: 'columnName4' },
              { VarCharValue: 'columnName5' },
              { VarCharValue: 'columnName6' }
            ]
          },
          {
            Data: [
              { VarCharValue: 'fieldValue1' },
              { VarCharValue:  123.4 },
              { VarCharValue:  false },
              { VarCharValue:  12 },
              { VarCharValue: 'fieldValue5' },
              { VarCharValue:  231.1 }
            ]
          }
      ]
   },
   "UpdateCount": number
}
```

where at *ColumnInfo* there are all the information about the columns present in the CSV (name, type information etc) and in the *Row* array are present all the information about the row: the columns and the related values splitted in two *Data* objects

My question is: is it possible to get the data from QueryResultCommand (or another command) with a better structure where the 2 *Data* objects are already "merged" so it easier to manage the rows and get their values by column name?

Or, do I have to handle every single element in the ROW array and create my own object?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html#getQueryResults-property) for the Athena SDK,we see that it does not support different formats for the returned data. I have pasted the available parameters below. The only other way I see would be to use the CLI which has an option to return the data in a different format.

```
Parameters:

params (Object) (defaults to: {}) —
QueryExecutionId — (String)
The unique ID of the query execution.

NextToken — (String)
A token generated by the Athena service that specifies where to continue pagination if a previous request was truncated. To obtain the next set of pages, pass in the NextToken from the response object of the previous page call.

MaxResults — (Integer)
The maximum number of results (rows) to return in this request.
```